# Why is this on resistance so high on P10NK70ZFP MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, resistance

I bought a batch of ten P10NK70ZFP N-channel MOSFETs [from here](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/185056520223?hash=item2b163a681f:g:K7cAAOSwQcJhRQG1&frcectupt=true), but after doing some testing I found that their on resistance is much higher than what the datasheet suggests.

The [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stp10nk70zfp.pdf) says that the maximum R<sub>ds(on)</sub> should be 0.85 Ω maximum and 0.75 Ω typical.

I tested this by raising the gate source voltage to 10 V and placed 5 V across drain/source and measuring the current. I measured around 0.3 A which means the resistance is 16.66 Ω.

I went through and tested all 10 of them and got the same on resistance. Is there something wrong with my test? How could this on resistance be so high?

Comment: See the rough finish on the body where the designation is? This indicates that the original part number has been filed off and replaced with a different one. Why they do it is beyond me. All that effort just to annoy their customers and get a bad reputation.

Comment: Well they have definetly succeeded in annoying me. I'll make sure to look out for those subtle defects in the future. Thank you

Comment: This is very common when buying parts on Ebay, AliExpress, etc. If you want genuine parts, buy from a reputable electronics parts distributor. (examples: Mouser, DigiKey, Farnell)

Comment: Have you _simultaneously_ measured current and voltage? It would be that your 5V source + ampmeter has a significant series resistance, and you are measuring that. Also, as pointed out, the standard measurement uses a constant current source of 4.5A, not a constant voltage source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test is not perfect, the parts are specified with more like 3-4V Vds, but, yeah, you got some counterfeit parts there.

Comment: _"the parts are specified with more like 3-4V Vds"_ - Rdson is specified at Vgs = 10V and Id = 4.5A, Vds is whatever results from that. But that is ~17W at 0.85 Ohms, so measurement would have to be done quickly to avoid heating effects.

Comment: @BruceAbbott yes, 3 or 4V. For the OP: When Vds starts to get high compared to Vgs(th) you get more of a resistance increasing with voltage (constant-ish current) and the spec is at 25 degrees C junction so it might increase 50% as the junction heats. But those two effects are nowhere near enough to account for the discrepancy.